# combinatorics and over counting

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

Say I want to have a eight card hand consisting of three cards that share a rank, 3 cards that share a different rank, and two cards that share a different rank. How many different eight card hands do we have?

$$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$

I seem to be over counting by $2$. I was wondering why this is? And if someone could explain to be where and why I am over counting. Also, are my choices right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 Kings -- 3 Queens are counted twice, once when the Kings are the first rank (i.e. number) counted, and once when the Queens are the first rank counted.

The correct approach is to compute the number of distinct ways of choosing the two ranks out of 13 that will each have a triplet :: $\binom{13}{2} = \frac{(13)!}{(11)!(2)!}.$

Other than that, everything else in your answer looks good, including your use of $\binom{4}{2}$ to designate the number of distinct ways of choosing two cards of the same rank (i.e.two cards out of 4).

Note that the reason that this overcounting trap exists in your query is that two of the ranks will have triplets.  If instead, you wanted (for example) 1 rank - quadruplet, 1 rank - triplet, and 1 rank pair, then your computation of the ranks as $(13 \times 12 \times 11)$ would be correct.

Comment: So I would leave $\binom{4}{3}$ in there twice because we choose the rank of the two cards from $\binom{13}{2}$?

Comment: @PeterP. I would have enumerated $\binom{13}{2} \binom{11}{1} \binom{4}{3} \binom{4}{3} \binom{4}{2}$.  The two factors of $\binom{4}{3}$ correspond to your needing (for example) to choose 3 Kings out of 4 and 3 Queens out of 4.

Comment: What do you mean when it says that my ranks will have triplets? I am having a hard time visualizing this.

Comment: @PeterP. "I want to have a eight card hand consisting of three cards that share a rank, 3 cards that share a different rank, and two cards that share a different rank."  Difference in semantics.  I am referring to three cards that share a rank as a triplet, and two cards that share a rank as a pair.

Comment: @PeterP.  To better visualize why the overcounting occurred, pretend that you have a 12 card deck (4 Aces, 4 dueces, 4 threes) and that you want 3 of one rank, 3 of another rank, and 2 of the third rank.  Actually count it out manually, and then compare the results with your original formula.  Similarly change the problem to 4 of one rank, 3 of another rank, and 2 of the third rank.  Then count this out manually, and then analytically.

Answer (score 1):

$13C3$ ways to choose 3 ranks. $3C1$ ways for one of them to be a pair. 4 ways to select one suit to exclude in 3 of a kind. $4C2$ ways to choose 2 out of 4 suits for the pair. So;
$$(13C3)(3)(4)^2(4C2)$$